# Login failed for user a\b

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, authentication, connection-string, ssms

I created a SQL connection as below:

```
SqlConnection scSqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server= " + ".\\" + strInstanceName + ";Initial Catalog=" + "master" + ";Integrated Security=True;");
```

and when I try to open this connection in my application there's no problem so I expect to be able to connect via SSMS in `windowsAuthentication` mode, but when I try to connect via SQL server management with `Server name = .\strInstanceName` in `windowsAuthentication` mode, I get the following error :

> login failed for user a\b

Would you, please, help me ?

Comment: Check if you SQL server authentication mode is set to mixed.

Comment: @Bayeni: yes it is mixed mode

Comment: If you login with this user through SQL Management Studio does is login?

Comment: @Bayeni : as I explained in my question , I can open connection via C# code in my application but I cant connect via SSMS with the same server name

Comment: `strInstanceName` is a variable declared somewhere in your code. You have to use whatever value is assigned to it, not the variable itself.

Comment: the details of login failure will be found in the event viewer. you could visit there to find more details about and post the error code, so it'll be easier to help