# How to change user of windows authentication connection string in C#

Tags: c#, connection-string, ssms, windows-authentication

When I want to connect to SQL Server 2008 via SSMS in windows authentication mode I get the following error:

```
login failed for user UserDomainName\UserName
```

I installed my SQL Server in mix mode and set user to NT Authority\system , how can I create a connection string with "UserDomainName\UserName" user not with "NT Authority\system" user in C#?

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: What do you want? To connect with SSMS (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) or a connection string which can be used in an application you developed?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for the correct format for a SQL Authentication string if thats what you asking (which is not clear) - You cannot manually specify credentials for a Windows Authentication logon.

Comment: @JanHenke: I have tried the connection string written in this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987296/login-failed-for-user-a-b]

Comment: Do you want sql or windows authentication?

Comment: @Waescher : connection string which can be used in an application I developed

Comment: ensure that the user has a login and permissions in SQL Server?

Comment: windows authentication runs under the user that owns the process opening the connection, it doesn't matter what account the server runs under.  You need to create an SQL Server login for UserDomainName\UserName then create a user for them.

Answer (score 1):

Store the connection string in `Web.Config` or `App.Config` file

```
<connectionStrings>
<Add name="CS" ConnectionString="DataSource=.;Database=Sample;Integrated Security=SSPI" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

then you can read the connection string property using `System.Configuration` namespace (dll)

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
```

> how can I create a connection string with "UserDomainName\UserName"
>   user not with "NT Authority\system" user in C#?

Then use SQL Authentication mode and not windows authentication

```
ConnectionString="DataSource=.;Database=Sample;user id = test; password=test"
```

Comment: thanx but my problem is not from where I need to read connection string , I need a connection string that work with current user not NT Authority user

Comment: Yah ... I red the comments you made in other answer and looks like you yourself have no real idea what you want or trying to achieve. edit your post and make it clear.

Comment: Ok ... please check edit in answer if that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It should something like this:

```
string address = "data source=(local);initial catalog=yourDB;user id=sa;password=yourPass";
```

Or:

```
string address = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=yourDB;Integrated Security=True";
```

You can check this for more: [SQL Server 2008 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/)

**Edit:** `Integrated Security` will always use the current identity. So you won't be able to establish a connection with Windows Authentication with credentials from another domain. You need to create an SQL Server login for `UserDomainName\UserName` like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=UserDomainName\UserName;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: I need a windows connection string not a sql authentication one

Comment: I created a connection string as :
'SqlConnection scSqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server= " + ".\\" + strInstanceName + ";Initial Catalog=" + "master" + ";Integrated Security=True;")' but it uses "NT autority\syatem" user but I need to use my "UserDomainName\UserName" user instead

Comment: @Shima.Y...Well replace`sa` with your `UserDomainName\UserName` ?

Comment: @Shima.Y...You want this: `Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=UserDomainName\UserName;Password=myPassword;`

Comment: thanx , so would you help me that why in my installedshield I can open my connection sql and when I run command and get user , results "Nt Authority\System" but when Im login into my app with the same SQL connection and connection string it says "login failed for userDomainName\UserName" both of connection strings are window sand are the same

Comment: @Shima.Y...Probably you have a typo somewhere. Check your connection string to match to exactly what I said and also refer to link that I mentioned.